# Loading custom View Controllers from a Bundle fails - "Unknown class in Interface Builder file"

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, bundle

I'm using the code below to present the initial View Controller from a Bundle.

```
NSString *path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Library/ReMoreTesting.bundle"];
NSBundle *bun = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"ReMoreTesting" bundle:bun];
UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateInitialViewController];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

However, `presentViewControllerAnimated:completion` causes an error to be logged: "Unknown class RMTViewController in Interface Builder file". The layout loads fine, but if I click something which relies on RMTViewController (anything not in the standard ViewController definition), it crashes with "unrecognized selector".

It seems to me that the Storyboard file is loading, but the class file, which is compiled and stored in the same Bundle, isn't being called. Am I missing something which specifies where to look for the class?

Thanks!

Also, yes, this is a dynamically loaded library, and I know the app won't pass Apple's approval for submission to the App Store. Also, I can successfully access the code from another method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While posting this question, I figured out the problem. I figured I'd post it anyways.

It turns out that loading the Storyboard doesn't load the Bundle's library as well. Calling `[bun load]` before instantiating the Storyboard resolved the issue.

Everything's easy in hindsight, eh?